# Keys do not work while using Keys.Down (Or up, left, right)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a beginner at C# (C Sharp) and I couldn't figure out why my Arrow keys would not work. Can anyone help me? Note: I am a beginner, I have been working at this for a while now and I can't figure it out. I have tried researching it with no luck, I hope I don't bother you. When I try and move it it doesn't work.

Here is my Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics paper;
    Snake snake = new Snake();

    bool left = false;
    bool right = false;
    bool down = false;
    bool up = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        paper = e.Graphics;
        snake.drawSnake(paper);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down && up == false)
        {
            down = true;
            up = false;
            right = false;
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up && down == false)
        {
            down = false;
            up = true;
            right = false;
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right && left == false)
        {
            down = false;
            up = false;
            right = true;
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left && right == false)
        {
            down = false;
            up = false;
            right = false;
            left = true;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (down) { snake.moveDown(); }
        if (up) { snake.moveUp(); }
        if (right) { snake.moveRight(); }
        if (left) { snake.moveLeft(); }

        this.Invalidate();
    }
 }
```

}
Here is my Snake class if you need it.

{

```
    public Snake()
    {
        snakeRec = new Rectangle[3];
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

        x = 20;
        y = 0;
        width = 10;
        height = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < snakeRec.Length; i++)
        {
            snakeRec[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            x -= 10;
        }
    }
    public void drawSnake(Graphics paper)
    {
        foreach (Rectangle rec in snakeRec)
        {
            paper.FillRectangle(brush, rec);
        }
    }

    public void drawSnake()
    {
        for (int i = snakeRec.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            snakeRec[i] = snakeRec[i - 1];
        }
    }

    public void moveDown()
    {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].Y += 10;
    }
    public void moveUp()
    {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].Y -= 10;
    }
    public void moveRight()
    {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].X += 10;
    }
    public void moveLeft()
    {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].X -= 10;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As I said I really am a beginner and I learn by looking, is there a way you could show me?

Comment: Have you tried just calling moveDown?

Comment: No I have not, can you show me in code?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is not working? The snake can be controlled when the code is executed.

Comment: When I debug it, I can not move the snake using my arrow keys. I hope I am not derping up. For me the snake can NOT be controlled.

Comment: I think while in the debugger, the windows is not repainted, so your code is working, but you are not able to see the progress. This is somehow a catch with WinForm UI's and debugging - window is not repainted. Try your program without the debugger at first. Maybe [this explanation on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255078/gui-does-not-redraw-while-stepping-in-debug-mode) could help - it addresses the issue.

Comment: Alright thanks. I will see.

Comment: @pasty It just won't repaint it. I don't know why it might do this though.

Comment: Got it! Had to link it. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works well, so this is the only thing I can think of:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Make sure that big guy is enabled.

Comment: I thought of the same, but it could be that it is started directly from the properties.

Comment: :P I've got it enabled. Still doesn't work. It doesn't move when I click the arrow keys.

Comment: @user3002617 I know the method works (change the Text of the form inside the tick event and you will see the title bar changing). So maybe it is not drawing it right?

Comment: @user3002617 it is working fine for me. Make sure all of your events are bound correctly (redrawing the snake and everything, is actually cool :D)

Comment: @HanletEscaño Thanks! What do you mean by "Make sure all of your events are bound correctly"?

Comment: AHA! I figured it out. My KeyDown "Event" I guess was not linked to my Form1_KeyDown, thank you all for your help. Derp!

Comment: @user3002617 that's exactly what I meant, that each event was "bound", or wired up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hold on to the Graphics from the Paint() event like that.  Just pass `e.Graphics` directly to your Draw() method like this:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        snake.drawSnake(e.Graphics);
    }
```

Also, make sure the Paint() event of the Form is wired up.  Select the Form.  Now click the "Lightning" Bolt" icon in the Properties Pane (bottom right by default).  Find the Paint entry and change the dropdown to the right to "Form1_Paint".