# When does a Windows thread need a message loop and why?

Tags: windows, multithreading

When do I need a message loop in a Windows application?

For example, for a Windows service do I need a message loop for every thread that I created or just for the main service process?

```
while(true)
{
    GetMessage(&messageHandle, 0, 0, 0);
    DispatchMessage(&messageHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every native Windows programs contains at least one message loop (often called a "message pump") like the one you give an example of.

This is to enable the handling of Windows events initiated by the program itself, other applications or the operating system.

Example of Windows events can be for timers, socket communication, GUI actions, clipboard, etc.

Many APIs and frameworks implement a message loop for you. This will depend on what you are using in your particular case.

(Check the answers in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222365/what-is-a-message-pump) for more information on message loops/message pump.)

Now to the gist of your question: many or most programs will work fine with one message-loop. The cases where you would want more than one is typically if processing a Windows event can take a long time (i.e. it locks the current thread) and there are requirements that require you too keep processing new window events. I can think of two concrete examples:

1. One is in a GUI application where you're showing a modal dialog (which usually freezes the main message pump and spins up a new one for the dialog)
2. A service of some kind where processing of I/O events can take a long time because of external dependencies and timeliness of processing of new I/O events is critical

In (1) this is very often a consequence of the GUI framework you are using and not something you have to do explicitly. In (2) a better way of handling it would be to asynchronously "do the work" of each event rather than blocking the message pump.

In conclusion: it depends. :-) In most cases you shouldn't need to use more than one message loop, but if you have to, do it!

Answer (score 0):

Apps:

Essentially, when the thread is going to create and manage windows.  This includes 'hidden' windows that support COM STA and the like.

No windows, no windows messages, no message loop required.

Services:

Service manager needs to handle the service messages, and so requires a service message loop for Start/Stop/whatever.

For other threads started in a service, no message loop is required.

Comment: You don't need a message loop in a service. The service manager will call your OnStart / OnStop etc from its own thread. You might need your own loop of course but it is not required.