# How is an event parameter passed?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I've noticed in C# I can override methods in the Form() parent class, like so:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I don't understand how `PaintEventArgs` is generated and how/when it is passed to this function. I've got to assume `OnPaint()` is called every time the form needs repainting.

Furthermore, when I create button press events they look like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Once again, I don't understand how/why these parameters are passed when a button click is activated.

Comment: The one overrides a protected virtual method while the other is a typical event handler to be attached to an event. The fact that you get sth called `PaintEventArgs` in OnPaint seems to me sheer lazyness/pragmatism of the implementors and doesn't follow any conventions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing special about it. The base class that defines the `Paint` event contains code morally equivalent to this:

```
protected virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{    
    var paintHandlers = this.Paint;
    if (paintHandlers != null)
    {
        paintHandlers(this, e);
    }
}
```

`OnPaint` serves two functions:

1. Raises the `Paint` event so external subscribers can be notified (that's how a hypothetical `form1_Paint` will eventually get called).
2. Lets derived classes directly respond to paint events without needing to involve an event handler -- simply override the method (but the derived class must not forget to call the base implementation!).

When the time comes to raise the `Paint` event, some other code in the base class creates a `PaintEventArgs` instance based on information at hand and calls `OnPaint`:

```
// ...somewhere in the class...
OnPaint(new PaintEventArgs(...));
```

In the special case where the event argument is typed as `EventArgs` there is no need to create a new instance, you can directly pass the [`EventArgs.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty.aspx) static member to the `OnSomething` method.

As to the *when* this happens: whenever a message is drawn from the application's [message pump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222365/what-is-a-message-pump) and processing it indicates that the event should be raised. You might also want to read [Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start is to (re?)familiarize yourself with .Net "delegates":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

For example, if you looked at the code for a C# form, you might see something like this:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // My code goes here...
```

Now if you looked at the corresponding, auto-generated, .Design code, you'd see something like this:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.btnGo.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnGo_Click);
    ....
```

The "+=" syntax assigns your custom event handler to the button.  Any tutorial on "delegates" (*including* the link I cited above) will give you more details about how and why this works.

I hope that helps .. PSM

Comment: -1 for posting a .NET 1.1 link. What happens when a reader starts clicking links from that page?

Comment: @retailcoder - thank you - I was working on that when my Internet connection went dead.  Updated now :)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the button click event handler, the `object sender, EventArgs e` syntax allows for multiple buttons to be wired up to a single event handler. This is possible, because the `sender` is the object that initiated the event, thus you can differentiate if button1, button2 or button3 initiated the event.

And since the `sender` is an `object`, then you could conceivably have a single click handler that handled all page elements that were clickable and have a bunch of conditional logic in the handler to switch based on what type of control initiated the event; this is not recommended though.