# UI thread is blocked

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In MainWindow I have `async` method which displays busy Indicator

```
public async Task BusyLoaderAsync(Action doWorkAction)
    {
        using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            await loadingPanel.StartSpinAsync(tokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(doWorkAction);

            tokenSource.Cancel();

            await loadingPanel.StopSpinAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Loading Panel looks like :

```
<Grid Panel.ZIndex="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="{Binding PanelLoading, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
        <controls:LoadingPanel x:Name="loadingPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    IsLoading="{Binding PanelLoading}"
                    Message="Calculating..."
                    SubMessage="Wait a minute"
                               />
    </Grid>
```

Control Loading Panel has 2 additional methods :

```
public async Task StartSpinAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int delay;
        if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationDelay"], out delay))
        {
            delay = 0;
        }
        await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => IsLoading = true,
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task StopSpinAsync()
    {
        await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => IsLoading = false,
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }
```

We want to show loader only if it realy takes time. Cause when some task executes less than some delay - it is like blink.

When I need to show indicator I try next :

```
_mainWindow.BusyLoaderAsync(() => _resultViewModel.InitChart(lineChart, generalChart)).ConfigureAwait(false); // code which initialize WPF toolkit chart as example
```

Problem - when indicator is shown, it doesn't spining, it is freezed. I think it is because UI thread is blocked.

Is it possible to check what block UI thread and is it possible to check it from code above?

Comment: A very simple check, execute your app, wait to your loader show up and not spinning, pause the execution and check the Threads panel to see where your code is paused, the first thread should be the UI thread.

Comment: @Gusman, yes, first thread is Main Thread, which in WPF is UI Thread as I know

Comment: It wasn't a question, I mean, if you go to that thread and to the call stack you will see what is blocking the UI thread...

Comment: @Gusman, well, then I can't detect what method block UI... In CallStack I can see just this http://i.imgur.com/BmrE9gL.png and no My Method

Comment: It seems like something is blocking a control creation

Comment: Try this instead: `_mainWindow.BusyLoaderAsync(() => _resultViewModel.InitChart(lineChart, generalChart));`, note the removal of the `ConfigureAwait`

Comment: @DavidPine, whithout it indicator is always unvisible

Comment: I would expect Task.Run(doWorkAction), if you want to run it in the background.

Comment: Your UI thread, like any thread, can do only one thing at a time.  It can animate your spinner *or* it can execute the doWorkAction target.  It cannot do both.  There is no asynchronicity in this code beyond the Delay() calls.

Comment: @HansPassant, well now I am agree with You. What you can suggest ?

Comment: @HansPassant, What can you said about this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009151/how-does-running-several-tasks-asynchronously-on-ui-thread-using-async-await-wor ?

Comment: When you do `ConfigureAwait(false)` means the task will execute on different TaskScheduler and not on the one which is associated with UI thread. When you have things to perform on UI you might want to execute respective task on UI thread. Keeping that in mind re-visit your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is problematic implementation of `BusyLoaderAsync(Action doWorkAction)` because it depends on `doWorkAction` implementation.
If `doWorkAction` is synchronous like:

```
BusyLoaderAsync(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(" == Action Start ");
    Thread.Sleep(8000);
    Debug.WriteLine(" == Action End ");
});
```

then it locks UI thread, and nothing updates in UI until `doWorkAction` ends. After it ends, `tokenSource.Cancel();` cancels the busy indicator, and it can never updates.

If `doWorkAction` is asynchronous like:

```
BusyLoaderAsync(async () =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(" == Action Start ");
    await Task.Delay(8000);
    Debug.WriteLine(" == Action End ");
});
```

then `doWorkAction` runs faster then `StartSpinAsync` and eventually `tokenSource.Cancel();` cancels the busy indicator before it starts, and it also never indicates.

In synchronous case, if `doWorkAction` can run in another thread, `BusyLoaderAsync` can be as following

```
public async Task BusyLoaderAsync(Action doWorkAction)
{
    using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var tasks = new[] { Task.Run(doWorkAction), Task.Delay(1000) };
        var result = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
        if (result == 1)
        {
            loadingPanel.IsLoading = true;
            await tasks[0];
            loadingPanel.IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
}
```