# Get current active Language keyboard

Tags: c++, winapi

I want get active language keyboard

for get active language i use this function :

```
WCHAR name[256];

GUITHREADINFO Gti;
::ZeroMemory(&Gti, sizeof(GUITHREADINFO));
Gti.cbSize = sizeof(GUITHREADINFO);
::GetGUIThreadInfo(0, &Gti);
DWORD dwThread = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(Gti.hwndActive, 0);
HKL lang = ::GetKeyboardLayout(dwThread);

LANGID language = (LANGID)(((UINT)lang) & 0x0000FFFF); // bottom 16 bit of HKL is LANGID
LCID locale = MAKELCID(language, SORT_DEFAULT);

GetLocaleInfo(locale, LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, name, 256);

return CString(name);
```

but this function retrieve One last with the last change (not new language), but i want to get new language, what is problem? what is wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "active language keyboard". Please also explain the steps to see that it only shows the last change.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk suppose, I have 3 language active in my system (US, Chinese And French) now, I want get That language is that active in my system(when I change language with Alt+Shift , what is active port, tell me

Answer (score 2):

From the doucmentation ([GetKeyboardLayout function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296(v=vs.85).aspx)), when a `0` is used as a default parameter it gets the keyboard layout from the current thread:

```
HKL lang = ::GetKeyboardLayout(0);
```

To create a language id, the following macro is used:

```
#define MAKELANGID(p, s)       ((((WORD  )(s)) << 10) | (WORD  )(p))
```

Also defined are the following helper macros:

```
#define PRIMARYLANGID(lgid)    ((WORD  )(lgid) & 0x3ff)
#define SUBLANGID(lgid)        ((WORD  )(lgid) >> 10)
```

So I just fixed up the code to be:

```
LANGID language = PRIMARYLANGID(lang);
```

And it works correctly for me.

To listen to keyboard changes the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message should be processed.

Actually you have to have a message loop in the thread specified otherwise changes to the language are not detected until you restart the app, a console app is a good example.[[2](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?360951)]

Comment: @Mr.DeveloperCplus Did this help?

Comment: tanks for your help, But actually this not correct answer and when I change language it's tell me language is English, But isn't, I want use this code in Key-logger.

Comment: if put this code in while loop with condition true it demonstrate first language

Comment: If you did a for, do, while loop - it is wrong. You need a message pump loop.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223270/2504757. But You need a window id for this to work correctly. This should be done in a GUI app, not a console app.