# How can you pump a STA Thread in a non-WinForms assembly?

Tags: c#, com, interop, sta

Hans gives this great answer about pumping an STA thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/197229

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class STAThread : IDisposable {
    public STAThread() {
        using (mre = new ManualResetEvent(false)) {
            thread = new Thread(() => {
                Application.Idle += Initialize;
                Application.Run();
            });
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            mre.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    public void BeginInvoke(Delegate dlg, params Object[] args) {
        if (ctx == null) throw new ObjectDisposedException("STAThread");
        ctx.Post((_) => dlg.DynamicInvoke(args), null);
    }
    public object Invoke(Delegate dlg, params Object[] args) {
        if (ctx == null) throw new ObjectDisposedException("STAThread");
        object result = null;
        ctx.Send((_) => result = dlg.DynamicInvoke(args), null);
        return result;
    }
    protected virtual void Initialize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        mre.Set();
        Application.Idle -= Initialize;
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.Send((_) => Application.ExitThread(), null);
            ctx = null;
        }
    }
    private Thread thread;
    private SynchronizationContext ctx;
    private ManualResetEvent mre;
}
```

But it relies on calls like Application.Run which is a Windows Forms class, I don't think I want in a non-UI static library.

So is there a way to tweak this, or perhaps it could even be used as is?

Comment: You can interop GetMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222365/what-is-a-message-pump it's not strictly equivalent to Application.Run but may be sufficient depending on your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `AsyncContextThread` from `Nito.AsyncEx.Context` nuget by Stephen Cleary. From its [github description](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext#asynccontextthread-api)

> AsyncContextThread provides properties that can be used to schedule tasks on that thread.

The nuget contains a custom implementation of `SynchronizationContext`, so the code could be easily rewritten e.g. as:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Nito.AsyncEx;

class STAThread : IDisposable
{
    public STAThread()
    {
        ctx = new AsyncContextThread();
    }

    public void BeginInvoke(Delegate dlg, params Object[] args)
    {
        ctx.Context.SynchronizationContext
            .Post((_) => dlg.DynamicInvoke(args), null);
    }

    public object Invoke(Delegate dlg, params Object[] args)
    {
        object result = null;
        ctx.Context.SynchronizationContext
            .Send((_) => result = dlg.DynamicInvoke(args), null);
        return result;
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        ctx.JoinAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        ctx.Dispose();
    }

    private readonly AsyncContextThread ctx;
}
```

Btw, from [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext#notes-on-synchronizationcontext-implementations), not all implementations of `SynchronizationContext` guarantee that delegates will be executed on specific thread, while WinForms and WPF `SynchronizationContext` guarantee that, default and ASP.NET do not.