# .NET Async / Await: How the State Machine knows when to continue it's execution?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

So i've read a lot of articles lately by trying to understand how the async methods works in the .NET world.

I've tried really hard to understand how an async call works, from actually calling `HttpClient.GetAsync("https://google.com")`, all the way down to how the OS initiates the call on the network card.
What bothers me is how the state machine knows when to call it's `MoveNext()` method.

From the network card, we have a system interrupt (once we have the request response), which seizes the control over the CPU for a brief moment. The CPU creates a so called `Deferred Procedure Call (DPC)` which the OS kernel keeps tracks of and executes these DPC's with high priority. After that the kernel initiates an `APC (asynchronous procedure call)` which, in bigger words, notifies the thread which made the async call and marks the `Task` as completed, and can resume it's execution.

My question is:

In a windows forms application, we have a UI Thread (which draws the window on the screen and responds to user events). Does this UI Thread have some sort of a `Task queue` which keeps on interogating from time to time, and asks if one of the tasks in the Completed state ? If yes, then everything makes sense, and my original question is answered. Once the OS sets the tasks as completed, and the UI thread sees that, it will call the `MoveNext()` method on it's State Machine.
But i heard recently that the UI Thread doesn't have this kind of `Task queue`. If this is the case, then how the OS, and internally the app itself, knows how to trigger the `MoveNext()` method ?

One assumption that i made, is that the OS injects the code of `MoveNext()` in whatever thread is currently available. But it still weird.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222365/what-is-a-message-pump) will be somewhat helpful?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/ You can refer to "Deconstructing an async method by hand" because it provides a simpler way to understand the logic behind.

Comment: It's called a message pump, and is how the UI thread receives callbacks which must execute on that thread (as well as obviously the more traditional window messages such as open/close/mouse/keyboard etc). Note that not all async calls go back to the UI thread, some stay on the threadpool threads, which have their own signalling mechanisms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> marks the Task as completed, and can resume it's execution.

Back up a bit first. I recommend [reading this blog entry of mine if you haven't already](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

When an `async` method performs an `await`, it first checks whether the operation is complete. In this case, it generally wouldn't be (but it's unwise to assume this; mobile platforms in particular heavily cache network requests and *can* complete them immediately). So let's assume the task returned from `GetAsync` is incomplete; in that case, the `async` method registers a continuation on that task.

But it's not *just* registering `MoveNext`; by default, `async` methods capture their current context (`SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`), and register a delegate that continues executing the `async` method *on that context*. If there is no context, then the continuation is scheduled to the thread pool.

> But i heard recently that the UI Thread doesn't have this kind of Task queue. If this is the case, then how the OS, and internally the app itself, knows how to trigger the MoveNext() method ?

That is correct. The UI thread does not have any notion of a task queue or what kinds of tasks it's waiting for. But it *does* have a message queue; this is the "main loop" of a UI thread. The OS sends it messages about mouse clicks and keyboard presses and a hundred other things besides. And it also supports custom (application-defined) messages. One of those custom message types is "run this delegate code on the UI thread".

The UI thread also has a `SynchronizationContext` - check out `SynchronizationContext.Current` in the debugger sometime. And this [`SynchronizationContext` can be used to schedule work on the UI thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) by sending itself a custom message to execute a specific delegate.

So, the `async` method will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` if present, and use that to schedule the continuation of the method; since it's a UI context, this means the continuation is sent as a message to the message loop, where the UI thread will (eventually) process it, continuing the `async` method on the UI thread.

Comment: And the relevant code in the case of WinForms is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs) and [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/control.cs,dc49fb4c2140594f).

Comment: Thanks for that @Stephen Cleary. Now the last puzzle piece is more clear. Also, the starting point in this journey was your "There is no Thread" article. A true inspiration :)